# jQuery Slideshow won't Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that similar questions have been asked before, but I am very much a rookie with my jQuery, and I cannot seem to get any of the solutions to work, so please forgive my naivety. I have created a very simple slideshow, but when the last slide is shown, it does not loop back to the beginning, it simply fades out. How can I make it loop continuously?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".featured > div:gt(0)").hide();

  setInterval(function() {
    $('.featured > div:first')
    .fadeOut(2000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .end()
    .replaceWith();
  }, 4000);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) completely removes whatever DOM element is calling it, so you have nothing to loop back to.

Try using [`.appendTo('.featured')`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) instead. That will move the first element to the end, enabling you to continue in an unending loop.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.featured > div:first')
        .fadeOut(2000)
        .next().fadeIn(2000).end()
        .appendTo('.featured');
}, 4000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JWc32/1/

**UPDATE:**

Depending on your page layout, you may want to do the `appendTo()` in a callback instead, so it doesn't move until the `fadeOut()` is complete:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.featured > div:first').fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $(this).appendTo('.featured');
    }).next().fadeIn(2000);
}, 4000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JWc32/3/

Comment: Thanks, that does cause it to loop, which is great! But now the new slide appears when the old slide is not yet fully faded out. Both slides appear one above the other for a second or so.

Comment: Wow, yes! Thank you, the top code worked best for me. I was also able to fix the issue in my comment above by changing .fadeout(2000) to .hide(), it now works beautifully. Thank you so much for your help!